# Why is my method returning all of my arrays?

Tags: ruby, hash, methods, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a choose-your-own-adventure style program. I'm creating three question arrays `q1`--`q3`, each with an array, another array, and a hash. The goal is to move through the array with my `question_charge` method then return what the next question array should be based on the user's answer.

```
puts "Please choose an answer to the following questions"

q1 = [["What is your answer to this very first question?"],["A - Option 1","B - Option 2","C - Option 3"],{"A" => q2,"B" => q3, "C" => q3}]
q2 = [["This is the second question, can I have an answer?"],["A - Option 2-1","B - Option 2-2","C - Option 2-3"],{"A" => q3,"B" => q3,"C" => q4}]
q3 = [["Question #3! What is your answer?"],["A - Option 3-1","B - Option 3-2","C - Option 3-3"]]

current_question = q1
def question_charge(current_question)
  x = 0
  puts current_question[x]
  x += 1
  puts current_question[x]
  answer = gets.chomp
  puts "You answered " + answer
  x += 1
  current_question = current_question[x][answer]
end

question_charge(current_question)
```

Sometimes when I run this, I receive the following error:

```
(eval):2: undefined local variable or method `q2' for main:Object (NameError)
```

When it does work, `q3` doesn't have a hash in the array as in the final question.  When I answer `'A'` to the first question, it returns all of my arrays multiple times. If I answer `'C'` for `q3`, it returns just fine. Can anyone tell me how I can return the only the array I want and without receiving an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining the first question, your hash is the following:

```
{"A" => q2,"B" => q3, "C" => q3}
```

but at that point, neither `q2` or `q3` are defined. You need to define `q2` and `q3` before you reference them.

Comment: So I just needed
    q1 = Hash.new
    q2 = Hash.new
    q3 = Hash.new
before I start throwing values into the hashes?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to rewrite you method to make more sense

```
def ask_question(current_question)
  question, options, next_question_hash = current_question

  puts question # "What is your answer to this very first question?"
  puts options  # "A - Option 1", ...

  answer = gets.chomp

  puts "You answer #{answer}"

  next_question = next_question_hash[answer]
end
```

This asks a question, and then returns the next question to answer.